# Add magic link for "welcome text"

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

It is very common to come across a user post a question that has many severe problems mentioned in the help pages. These are the users that are the least accustomed to the site, and weirdly, gets the least feedback as their questions gets downvoted into oblivion instantly.

I propose to have the existence of a magic link similar to [mcve] and other links that automatically expands to some "welcome text".

Examples of "welcome text"

> If you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Also please take the tour and read about how to ask good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example. – Some programmer dude

---

> Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read The Tour and refer to the material from the Help Center what and how you can ask here. – πάντα ῥεῖ

These are quite gruesome to type by hand, and unsurprisingly, there are many more people that downvotes than leave such a comment (despite the prompt from the site to leave a comment).

This is a very counter-productive pattern: the user has no idea what went wrong, sees the post annihilated sometime later and goes on to post again, effectively spamming the site.

This magic link will make leaving a comment not actually a taxing task and hopefully incentivise people into leaving comments more.

Comment: Note that you have the magic comment here to copy and paste when needed https://pastebin.com/Q3H7zcSn

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks, I was just about to compile one myself ;) But I sometimes use my phone and its just tedious to even find a page and copy-paste something.

Comment: Normally these are handle by a user script like [this one](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).  No idea if it works on mobile though.

Comment: @NathanOliver THANK YOU!